# Implement pretty checkbox css into rails form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have some pretty css for checkboxes (from here: https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/) that I'd like to replace the standard check-box

How do I do this?

The form code:

```
<div class="w-64 bg-gray-300 flex justify-between">
  <%= form.label :standard, class: "inline-block" %>
  <%= form.check_box :stretch, class: 'inline-block' %>
</div>

<div class="pretty p-icon p-round p-pulse">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="state p-success">
  <label>Pretty</label>
    <i class="icon mdi mdi-check"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

A screenshot showing the standard and the pretty one beneath it:

[image: screenshot of standard checkbox and the pretty one]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any succinct answer on how to do this. The other thing I wanted to do was to have the pretty checkbox to be in the same format as the standard one, i.e. text first, checkbox on the same line

The only way I found to do this was to put them in a table...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="bg-blue-100">Thing</th>
    <th><div class="text-white">blankspace</div></th>
    <th>Done?</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- TICK -->
    <td class="bg-blue inline">Stretch</td>
    <td><div class="text-white">blankspace</div></td>
    <td>
      <%= form.label :stretch, :class => 'pretty p-icon p-round p-pulse' do %>
      <%= form.check_box :stretch %>
      <div class="state p-success">
        <label></label>
        <i class="icon mdi mdi-check"></i>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
...
</table>
```

[image: who's a pretty boy then]